# What are the semantics of passing pointers as function arguments?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

There are some things that I still don't really understand with pointers when you pass them into functions.
If declare a function like

```
void help (const int *p)
```

can I modify the argument `p` within the function `help`? 
Can I change what the pointer is pointing too?

Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can modify `p`.  However, it won't change in the caller.  C is a pass-by-value language.  Check out the C FAQ, which has a question about [exactly this situation](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html).

Comment: Well, in that precise case you can't, since its declared 'const', but generally yep - see above.

Comment: Good call - I'll take that out.

Comment: Why can't the copy of `p` inside `help` be modified?  The `const` in the declaration should only mean that `p` points to constant data, hence a statement like `*p = 5` shouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, since `p` is declared as a `const int *`, an attempt to modify `p` will be disallowed by the compiler.

However, if `p` were a plain old `int *`, you could modify the thing that `p` is pointing to, and the caller would notice.  Say you wrote:

```
void foo(void) {
    int n = 100;

    help1(&n);
    printf("n = %d", n);

    n = 100;
    help2(&n);
    printf("n = %d", n);
}

void help1(int *p) {
    *p = 50;
}

void help2(int *p) {
    p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *p = 50;
    free(p);
}
```

Then calling `foo()` would cause your program to print

```
n = 50
n = 100
```

In this program, `help1` changes the thing that `p` points to, and the caller can see it.  On the other hand, `help2` makes `p` point to a different place in memory, and anything `help2` does to modify that other location in memory is not visible to the caller.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to understand const notation in C is to say the declaration out loud. Start with the name and go left:

```
const int *p; // 'p' is a pointer to an int that is const
```

This is by the way equal to:

```
int const *p;
```

This suggests that you can change the what p points at, but you can't change whatever it points at. So you have read-only access. However if you'd have something like this:

```
int * const p; // 'p' is a const pointer to an int
```

...then you could change the memory pointed to by p as much as you want, but you couldn't change `p`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. So if it is "int const *p;" I can change the value of *p but I can change where it points at in the memory and the opposite for "int * const p;"

Comment: Yes. 'int const *p' / 'const int *p' means that you can change 'p', but not '*p'. And the opposite for 'int * const p'.